# Is there a meaning for __atomic_signal_fence(__ATOMIC_RELAXED)

Tags: c, gcc, atomic, memory-barriers

__atomic_signal_fence act as an optimize barrier for compiler, and it accept all memory order, includes __ATOMIC_RELAXED.

While, __ATOMIC_RELAXED means no memory order at all.
For atomic operations like __atomic_add_fetch, it means only atomic operation is assured.

For similar __atomic_thread_fence, it requires an atomic read before or an atomic write after the fence, give the meaning of __atomic_thread_fence.

But for __atomic_signal_fence, optimize barrier is it's meaning of all. With __ATOMIC_RELAXED, nothing left.

So, is it effectively  same for

```
__atomic_signal_fence(__ATOMIC_RELAXED);
```

with

```
// __atomic_signal_fence(__ATOMIC_RELAXED);
```

Comment: You originally tagged this [stdatomic], but you're actually asking about [GNU C builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), *not* anything ISO C11 or ISO C++11 standardized (like `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_relaxed)`).  IDK if the ISO standards even define that because you're right, a `relaxed` fence should be a no-op, AFAIK.  https://godbolt.org/z/cfqrEYsfG shows them compiling to zero instructions for two weakly-ordered ISAs (POWER and RISC-V)

Comment: The GNU builtin declares in its documentation __atomic_xxx following the same semantic with c++11, so, I add this tag

Comment: Asm shows in godbolt.org/z/cfqrEYsfG does not make sense because atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_relaxed) only has meaning after an atomic read or before an atomic write; And atomic_signal_fence absolutely compiles to nothing, like asm(":::memory"), which equals to atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_seq_cst).  The atomic_signal_fence can't be observed from asm because it only affects instructions order of the others

Comment: Note that I used `atomic_thread_fence` to also force ordering of visibility to other threads, which would take instructions if any ordering was required.  (The compiler has to assume that the caller included loads+stores before and after.  This is irrelevant for signal_fence where only compile-time ordering matters, but not thread_fence.) Err, I did for C11, but accidentally still used `__atomic_signal_fence` which was useless. But yeah, you could put together examples like `shared = 1; fence; shared = 2;` and see if you still get dead-store elimination - we do: https://godbolt.org/z/srsvnoE34

Comment: Re: standards and docs: the GNU __atomic builtins are *at least* as strong as what ISO C++11 requires, and are used to implement that library.  But they might define the behaviour of things that ISO C++ doesn't.  If you want to also ask about ISO C++ fences, do so, so the C++ standard itself could be quoted in an answer.

Comment: oh, yes, relaxed is meaningless to thread fence either, I did not notice it before